# Creating thumbnails from directory with php loop

Tags: php, mysql, thumbnails

Ok i've been at this for a while and need some help.
I have a directory of 3000+ images that i need thumbnails of, and i can't quite get php to do it :(

I have never made thumbnails with php so this is new to me, I found a few scripts that create thumbnails as you upload images to the server, I will do this from here on out.

The image locations are stored as a URL in a mysql database.
I need it to create a thumbnail of the image and of course, update the database with the thumbnail url.

This is the script I'm using to integrate my needs into:
http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/how-to-dynamically-create-thumbnails/
I'm using the exact same functions.php & config.php files.

Here's what I got:
$row['image'] is the location of each image ex: http://www.url.com/images/image.jpg
$filename I'm stripping the url so it just serves image.jpg

```
<?php
    require 'config.php';  
    require 'functions.php';  
    require 'db.php';  
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pics");  
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_ASSOC)){  

        $filename = preg_replace('['.$url.']', '', $row['image']);              
        $source = $row['image'];

        createThumbnail($filename);

        $thumb_loc = $url . "images/thumbs/" . $filename;
        $id = $row['id'];
        mysql_query("UPDATE pics SET image_thumb = '$thumb_loc' WHERE id = '$id'");
    }
?>
```

I'm serving a proper filename to $filename and image source to $source, so it should be working..
Here is the createThumbnail function in functions.php:

```
<?
function createThumbnail($filename) {

    require 'config.php';

    if(preg_match('/[.](jpg)$/', $filename)) {
        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($path_to_image_directory . $filename);
    } else if (preg_match('/[.](gif)$/', $filename)) {
        $im = imagecreatefromgif($path_to_image_directory . $filename);
    } else if (preg_match('/[.](png)$/', $filename)) {
        $im = imagecreatefrompng($path_to_image_directory . $filename);
    }

    $ox = imagesx($im);
    $oy = imagesy($im);

    $nx = $final_width_of_image;
    $ny = $final_height_of_image;

    $nm = imagecreatetruecolor($nx, $ny);

    imagecopyresized($nm, $im, 0,0,0,0,$nx,$ny,$ox,$oy);

    if(!file_exists($path_to_thumbs_directory)) {
      if(!mkdir($path_to_thumbs_directory)) {
           die("There was a problem. Please try again!");
      }
       }

    imagejpeg($nm, $path_to_thumbs_directory . $filename);
    $tn = '<img src="' . $path_to_thumbs_directory . $filename . '" alt="image" />';
    $tn .= '<br />Congratulations. Your file has been successfully uploaded, and a    thumbnail has been created.';
    echo $tn;
}
?>
```

Here are the warnings:

```
Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(images/fullsized/image.jpg) [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in functions.php on line 7

Warning: imagesx(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource in functions.php on line 14

Warning: imagesy(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource in functions.php on line 15

Warning: Division by zero in functions.php on line 18

Warning: imagecreatetruecolor() [function.imagecreatetruecolor]: Invalid image dimensions in functions.php on line 20

Warning: imagecopyresized(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource in functions.php on line 22

Warning: imagejpeg(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource in functions.php on line 30
```

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  If not, have you enabled error_reporting?

Comment: Yea im getting a few warnings.        
Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(images/fullsized/image.jpg) [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in functions.php on line 7

Comment: Well, basically, it says that the file you are trying to open does not exist.  Perhaps you should try specifying a complete path, starting from root.

Comment: The images do exist at the url the loop is serving. I think it has something to do with the image being on a url instead of a file upload. Is there a way  to grab an image from a url, save it temporarily and serve it as a file, create a thumbnail and delete the temp image?

Comment: Also, it would help us if you stated how createThumbnail() is declared.  OK, maybe not.

Comment: I updated the post with the createThumbnail() function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be that path you are specifying for the image file to manipulate is not valid from the location of the script.

The file in the example is `images/fullsized/image.jpg` and the relevant error is `failed to open stream: No such file or directory in functions.php on line 7`

You will need to use an absolute path when telling `imagecreatefromjpeg` what file to open e.g. `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/images/fullsized/image.jpg'` or `/home/yoursite/public_html/images/fullsized/image.jpg`.

> A full path or absolute path is a path that points to the same
>   location on one file system regardless of the working directory or
>   combined paths. It is usually written in reference to a root
>   directory.

All of the other error messages are just side effects of the image failing to open.  Because the path was incorrect, no GD image was created and therefore the functions being called on it will not work.

Comment: I've removed the move_uploaded_file , as I'm not uploading or moving anything. Sorry, I updated the post.

Comment: @DavidIvanov I've updated the answer now to address the actual issue.

Comment: Well, @drew010, he says what the problem is.  Somehow you are not specifying an existing image to `imagecreatefromjpeg()`.  Perhaps you could echo out `$path_to_image_directory . $filename` to see what you are actually giving to that fuction.

Comment: @Zombaya From the looks of the error message, `images/fullsized/image.jpg` is what is being given to the function as that is the path contained in the database.  It needs to be adjusted for this particular script.

Comment: @Zombaya echoing $path_to_image_directory . $filename results in "images/fullsized/image.jpg"

Comment: @DavidIvanov Try changing the filename to this: `$filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . preg_replace('['.$url.']', '', $row['image']);`  The relative path stored in the database is not correct given the location you are running that script from.

Comment: @drew010 all the paths in the database aren't relative, they're full url location of the image. ex: http://www.url.com/images/image.jpg

Comment: @DavidIvanov Ok, I see that you are removing the URL from the beginning, it basically needs the URL removed and replaced with an absolute path.  Or move this script one directory above `images`.

Comment: Are urls not absolute paths?
I see what you're saying though, let me give it a shot.

Comment: @DavidIvanov URL's are absolute (when it comes to the internet), but in this case you don't necessarily want to use a URL.  You want to use the physical path of the file on the server.  If you are a windows user, `C:\Users\David\Documents\financials\accounts.xlsx` is the absolute path.  From the `Documents` directory, `financials\accounts.xlsx` is relative (to Documents).  PHP can open images using a URL, but this is disabled on many servers.